# Xamarin Forms Map - Center and Distance Update Multiple Pins

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm loading in and adding pins to a Xamarin Forms Map.

Using the following method to get the center Latitude/Longitude:

```
    public static Position GetCenter(List<Position> geoCoordinates)
    {
        if (geoCoordinates.Count == 1)
        {
            return geoCoordinates.Single();
        }

        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        double z = 0;

        foreach (var geoCoordinate in geoCoordinates)
        {
            var latitude = geoCoordinate.Latitude * Math.PI / 180;
            var longitude = geoCoordinate.Longitude * Math.PI / 180;

            x += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Cos(longitude);
            y += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Sin(longitude);
            z += Math.Sin(latitude);
        }

        var total = geoCoordinates.Count;

        x = x / total;
        y = y / total;
        z = z / total;

        var centralLongitude = Math.Atan2(y, x);
        var centralSquareRoot = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        var centralLatitude = Math.Atan2(z, centralSquareRoot);

        var dtoReturn = new Position(centralLatitude * 180 / Math.PI, centralLongitude * 180 / Math.PI);

        return dtoReturn;
    }
```

This gets me the CENTER:

```
        map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(CENTER, Distance.FromMiles(X));
```

My question is regarding the second parameter for `Radius`. What's the best way to calculate the Radius in miles?

```
Distance.FromMiles(X)
```

Comment: You have the center of the locations, so for a radius wouldn't you want to find the point furthest from the center and go off the distance between that point and the center?
How big is your potential dataset?

Comment: Hey @deckertron_9000 that's exactly what I'm doing for now! However it's not seemingly working correctly when the points are a couple hundred miles apart.. didn't know if there was a more precise way.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `MapSpan` from center, latitudeDegrees and longitudeDegrees like below.

```
private static MapSpan FromPositions(IEnumerable<Position> positions)
{
    double minLat = double.MaxValue;
    double minLon = double.MaxValue;
    double maxLat = double.MinValue;
    double maxLon = double.MinValue;

    foreach (var p in positions)
    {
        minLat = Math.Min(minLat, p.Latitude);
        minLon = Math.Min(minLon, p.Longitude);
        maxLat = Math.Max(maxLat, p.Latitude);
        maxLon = Math.Max(maxLon, p.Longitude);
    }

    return new MapSpan(
        new Position((minLat + maxLat) / 2d, (minLon + maxLon) / 2d),
        maxLat - minLat, 
        maxLon - minLon);
}
```